# Is this correct way to test rake log:clear? can not run ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, rake-task

Need help running [this](https://gist.github.com/pramodshinde/677ae4db3d95c4510c76) ruby script, I am trying to test the task `rake log:clear`

More details are here https://gist.github.com/pramodshinde/677ae4db3d95c4510c76

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve besides the script?

Comment: I want to test rake log:clear, but i am getting require specific issue.

Comment: Thats what you wrote already. But why are you testing a basic functionality of Rails?

Comment: I have changed the functionality of log:clear rake task to truncate files , so i have written the test case for this(https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22544) issue. I am writing the positive & negative test cases using this boilerplate ruby script provided by rails community.

Comment: Your question appears to be on github, please ask your question here.